# Copy Oracle stats without DDL

Tags: oracle

I need to copy stats from production to test database but all sample code I found use **create_stat_table** procedure, but I cannot create tables on source database. Is there any chance to do this different way? Maybe I can generate some INSERT statements from system views (like dba_tab_statistics) and run on destination db?

Comment: do you mean you can't create procedures? if so, what version of oracle database are you using, because we might have a trick for you to get around this limitation.

Comment: we have read-only access, we can query system views etc. but we can't create table using dbms_stats.create_stat_table which is normally used by dbms_stats.export_table_stats (it would require some additional requests for our admin which we want to avoid). I was thinking, if there is any way to generate data which normally is produced by export_table_stats and stored into new table created by create_stat_table. I know this data is produced somehow from dba_tab_statistics and dba_ind_statistics (which I can query) but don't know how...

Comment: you didn't' answer my question, so i can't answer yours...but end of day - you just need to have your DBA mange your stats - it's critical for the performance of your SQL and applications, so they should have no problems doing so

Comment: I can't create procedures, I can't run DDL on production database (on test I have full access). Oracle version is 11g

Comment: in 12c and higher, you can ad hoc create/use pl/sql via a WITH clause - w/o actually creating the plsql. But you're on 11g, so moot point

Comment: i see, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get_*_stats` to fetch the details from prod, then pass these by calling `set_*_stats` in test.

For example, get the stats like this:

```
create table t as 
  select level tid, date'2022-01-01' + level c1 
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 100;
  
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( user, 't' ) ;
  
declare
  numrows number;
  numblks number;
  avgrlen number;
begin
  dbms_stats.get_table_stats (
     ownname => user, 
     tabname => 'T', 
     numrows => numrows, 
     numblks => numblks,
     avgrlen => avgrlen
  );
  
  dbms_output.put_line ( 
    numrows || '; ' || numblks || '; ' || avgrlen 
  );
end;
/

100; 4; 11
```

Then load them like this (I'm dropping the table in the same DB for simplicity)

```
drop table t purge;
create table t ( tid integer, c1 date );

  NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS AVG_ROW_LEN
---------- ---------- -----------
<null>     <null>     <null>  

select num_rows, blocks, avg_row_len 
from   user_tables
where  table_name = 'T';

begin
  dbms_stats.set_table_stats (
     ownname => user, 
     tabname => 'T', 
     numrows => 10, 
     numblks => 4,
     avgrlen => 11
  );
end;
/

select num_rows, blocks, avg_row_len 
from   user_tables
where  table_name = 'T';

  NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS AVG_ROW_LEN
---------- ---------- -----------
        10          4          11
```

Copying the stats for all the columns and indexes this way is a faff though. If you need this, speak with whoever manages the database and get them to copy these over for you!